# How can is pass a parameter from one Python script to another remotely using Paramiko?

Tags: python, paramiko

I'm trying to pass variables form a Python code to another.

This is my code for testing purposes (it runs on my PC, no on RaspberryPi)

`script.py`

```
import paramiko
from flask import Flask
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Index"

@app.route('/led')
#def led(state):
 def led():
     #state = 'on'
     ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
     ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
     ssh.connect('myip', username = 'mypi', password = 'mypass')
     stdin, stdout, stderr = \
     ssh.exec_command('python /home/pi/Shield/led.py')
     return "LED ON"
    #return led(state)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)

if __name__ == "__led__":
    led()
```

This is the script that is on my RPi:

`led.py`

```
import time
import os
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)

state = sys.argv[1]

state = 'on'

if state == 'on'
     GPIO.output(11,True)
     time.sleep(1)
     GPIO.output(11,False)
     time.sleep(1)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

The code above works (LED blinks, if i change my URL to 0.0.0.0:5000/led), but it not elegant at all, and i need to do something similar to switch it off, which is stupid.

It is possible to pass that `state` variable from `script.py` to `led.py` ?

I will have 2 buttons, ON/OFF.

Comment: Did you tried `socket` communication ?

Comment: No, I didn't. What should I do ? All suggestions are welcome.